# Is there a simple way to get the filename from a path in c++?

Tags: c++, std

Currently I am getting a file's path with `GetModuleFileName` and storing it in szExeFilePath by doing:

```
TCHAR szExeFilePath[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileName(NULL, szExeFilePath, MAX_PATH);
```

And that returns `C:\\dev\\program\\Debug\\program.exe`

However I also want to store just the `program.exe`. I looked around and saw `_splitpath_s` might be the easiest way of doing this. The only problem is that I didn't see any explanation on how to actually use `_splitpath_s` and I can't get it to work at all.

**So basically I am asking how to use `_splitpath_s` or if there is a simpler/easier method of getting the filename of the executable.**

Comment: Are you trying to the get the file path of the current executable, or some other file?

Comment: Current Executable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However I also want to store just the program.exe

With C++17 you could simple use [`std::filesystem`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main()
{
    std::cout << fs::path("C:/dev/program/Debug/program.exe").filename() << '\n' ;
}
```

**<kbd>[Demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49b95732cc611242)</kbd>**

Comment: You should also just be able to use `fs::current_path()` instead of giving the hard-coded path

Comment: @P0W I am getting `filesystem is not a member of std`

Comment: @breadguy your compiler might nor be supporting C++17. See if you can try from experimental namespace `namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;` ?

Comment: @P0W Experimental namespace worked exactly as needed and as shown in the demo (with non-experimental). Just wondering is there something I should update since I am needing to use experimental. I am using Visual Studio 2017 to code in.

Comment: @breadguy As of the release of Visual Studio 2017, the <filesystem> header was not yet a C++ standard, I don't know when it will be updated for `std` . See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/filesystem)

Comment: @P0W What datatype do I need to use in order to store the result of `fs::current_path().filename();` in a variable called fname?

Comment: @breadguy it returns `path` however to convert into native string you could use the `string()' method on it . See [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/string)